# MongoDB query: sorting by data that may be in a field

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB query which works well except **the field 'department' in the reports collection can contain the data 'Shift Manager'. If it does, I would like that record to be returned first within each equipment group.**

```
db.collection('reports').aggregate([
{ $match: { date: { $gte: yesterday } } },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'equipment',
    localField: 'equipment',
    foreignField: 'equipment',
    as: 'equipmentInfo'
  }
},
{ $unwind: '$equipmentInfo' },
{ $sort: { 'equipmentInfo._id': 1 } },
{ $sort: { department: -1 } },
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
        equipmentId: '$equipmentInfo._id',
        name: '$name',
        shift: '$shift',
        date: '$date',
        department: '$department',
        equipment: '$equipmentInfo.equipment'
    },
    report: { $first: '$report' }
  }
},
{
    $sort: { '_id.equipmentId': 1 }
}
```

])

**The equipment collection is structured like this:**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("611c058a1556ba22f0ec0f6d"),
    equipment: "DCM 1"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("611c058a1556ba22f0ec0f6e"),
    equipment: "DCM 2"
  },
]
```

**The reports collection is structured like this:**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6284e804a96c8bb76a648e68"
  },
  "date": 1514851200000,
  "department": "Maintenance",
  "equipment": "DCM 1",
  "name": "Simo",
  "report": "machine shop start up . All cnc machine warmed up .",
  "shift": "Days"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6284e804a96c8bb76a648e69"
  },
  "date": 1514851200000,
  "department": "Shift Manager",
  "equipment": "DCM 7",
  "name": "Jim",
  "report": "bkw chiller motor had tripped . Reset all ok",
  "shift": "Days"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6284e804a96c8bb76a648e6a"
  },
  "date": 1514851200000,
  "department": "Process",
  "equipment": "DCM 14",
  "name": "Jack",
  "report": "bkw chiller had tripped . Reset all ok #\nlow on coolant. not topped up",
  "shift": "Days"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a field for this:
The three last steps are:

1. creating a `sortPriority` field
2. `$sort` by this field
3. `$unset` it

```
db.reports.aggregate([
  {$match: {date: {$gte: yesterday }}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "equipment",
      localField: "equipment",
      foreignField: "equipment",
      as: "equipmentInfo"
  }},
  {$set: {equipmentInfo: {$first: "$equipmentInfo"}}},
  {$sort: {department: -1, "equipmentInfo._id": 1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        equipmentId: "$equipmentInfo._id",
        name: "$name",
        shift: "$shift",
        date: "$date",
        department: "$department",
        equipment: "$equipmentInfo.equipment"
      },
      report: {$first: "$report"}
  }},
  {$set: {sortPriority: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.department", "Shift Manager"]}, 1, 0]}}},
  {$sort: {sortPriority: -1}},
  {$unset: "sortPriority"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pFFB2HQpfka)